Comparing 4 variables in one graph using Python
My aim is to do a comparison on 4 variables. My df looks like this:



Date
Hour
Idealised
Measured
Theoretical
Loss




2023-08-24
0
0
0
0
0


2023-08-24
1
72.7763
15.0539
13.7209
-1.3329


2023-08-24
2
180.2867
119.3180

59.7289


2023-08-25
0
174.4977
97.8154
51.7991
-46.0162


2023-08-25
1
153.8226
51.3554
35.1768
-16.1785


2023-08-25
2
130.6665
42.6032
29.7123
-12.8908


2023-08-26
0
13.2320
2.0793
2.0339
-0.0454


2023-08-25
1
3.8126
84.3504
144.1068
1.1623


2023-08-25
2
700.6435
98.3432
43.7923
2.8408



After cleaning and transforming the dataset, I tried the below code, but the resulting graph is not very readable. The y-axis is congested and not in numeric order:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

##############################
###     LOAD DATAFRAME     ###
##############################

df = pd.read_csv("analysis.csv")


##############################
###     CREATE LINE PLOT   ###
##############################

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

sns.lineplot(x="Hour", 
             y="Idealised", 
             data=df, 
             label="Perfect")

sns.lineplot(x="Hour", 
             y="Measured", 
             data=df, 
             label="Actual")

sns.lineplot(x="Hour", 
             y="Theoretical", 
             data=df, 
             label="Forecast")

sns.lineplot(x="Hour", 
             y="Loss", 
             data=df, 
             label="Loss")

Is there a way to make this easier on the eyes? I would like to split the df by day and then create the plot.

Make sure your "Hour", "Idealised", "Measured", "Theoretical", and "Loss" columns all have numerical datatypes. The results you show occur when using strings instead of numbers for plotting.

Does this meet your expectations?
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Date': ['2023-08-24', '2023-08-24', '2023-08-24', '2023-08-25', '2023-08-25', '2023-08-25', '2023-08-26', '2023-08-26', '2023-08-26'],
    'Hour': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    'Idealised': [0, 72.7763, 180.2867, 174.4977, 153.8226, 130.6665, 13.2320, 3.8126, 700.6435],
    'Measured': [0, 15.0539, 119.3180, 97.8154, 51.3554, 42.6032, 2.0793, 84.3504, 98.3432],
    'Theoretical': [0, 13.7209, None, 51.7991, 35.1768, 29.7123, 2.0339, 144.1068, 43.7923],
    'Loss': [0, -1.3329, 59.7289, -46.0162, -16.1785, -12.8908, -0.0454, 1.1623, 2.8408]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for date in df['Date'].unique():
    day_data = df[df['Date'] == date]
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    
    for column in ['Idealised', 'Measured', 'Theoretical', 'Loss']:
        plt.plot(day_data['Hour'], day_data[column], marker='o', label=column)
    
    plt.title(f'Values Over Time - {date.date()}')
    plt.xlabel('Hour')
    plt.ylabel('Values')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(range(0, 24, 1))
    plt.xlim(0, 23)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

Results in





import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

# Sample data (replace this with your actual data loading method)
data = """
DateHour,Idealised,Measured,Theoretical,Loss
2023-08-2401,72.7763,15.0539,13.7209,-1.3329
2023-08-2402,180.2867,119.3180,59.7289,0
2023-08-2500,174.4977,97.8154,51.7991,-46.0162
2023-08-2501,153.8226,51.3554,35.1768,-16.1785
2023-08-2502,130.6665,42.6032,29.7123,-12.9908
2023-08-2600,13.2320,2.0793,2.0339,-0.0454
2023-08-2601,3.8126,84.3504,144.1068,1.1623
2023-08-2602,700.6435,98.3432,43.7923,2.8408
"""

# Read the data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# Convert DateHour to datetime
df['DateHour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateHour'], format='%Y-%m-%d%H')

# Set DateHour as the index
df.set_index('DateHour', inplace=True)

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot each production type
measured, = ax.plot(df.index, df['Measured'], label='Measured', marker='o')
theoretical, = ax.plot(df.index, df['Theoretical'], label='Theoretical', marker='s')
idealised, = ax.plot(df.index, df['Idealised'], label='Idealised', marker='^')
loss, = ax.plot(df.index, df['Loss'], label='Loss', marker='D')

# Customize the plot
ax.set_title('Energy Production over 3 Days')
ax.set_xlabel('Date and Hour')
ax.set_ylabel('Energy Production')
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

# Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

# Adjust layout to prevent cutting off labels
plt.tight_layout()

# Function to update annotation on click
def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for line in [measured, theoretical, idealised, loss]:
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                x = line.get_xdata()[ind["ind"][0]]
                y = line.get_ydata()[ind["ind"][0]]
                annotation.xy = (x, y)
                annotation.set_text(f'Date and Time: {x}\nValue: {y:.2f}')
                annotation.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
                return
        annotation.set_visible(False)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# Create annotation object
annotation = ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords='offset points',
                         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='w'),
                         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))
annotation.set_visible(False)

# Connect the click event to the function
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

# Show the plot
plt.show()


It will provide detailed info of value and time on click at a particular point on graph

Added the image for refrence
